# Transform [:one, 1, :two, 2] to {:one => 1, :two => 2} in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the most most ruby-like way of converting from an `Array` like `[:one, 1, :two, 2]` to a `Hash` like `{:one => 1, :two => 2}`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Hash[*array]
```

Comment: Wow that's great, I never knew of that syntax before!

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[*[:one, 1, :two, 2]]
#=> {:one => 1, :two => 2}
```